# Parse.User in CloudCode error 141

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My Cloud Code defines some functions that make queries that require a _User object. According to my understanding of the Parse documentation, I could get the _User from the current request with `Parse.User.current()`

The problem is that it works some times, and others don't. It looks unstable.

These methods seems problematic:

- `Parse.User.become()`
- `Parse.User.current()`

**It throws a success in one second and a 141 error in the next second.**

Important: I'm testing with REST api, via CURL request, with the user validation via sessionToken in the header.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkUser", function (request, response) {
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  if (currentUser) {
    response.success( currentUser );
  } else {
    response.error("Error");
  }
});
```

I tried a different approach (just as a test), sending a sessionToken and then becoming the User, but got the same problems.

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("checkUser", function (request, response) {
   Parse.User.become(request.params.token).then(function (user) {
    response.success( user );
  }, function (error) {
    response.error("Error[" + error.code + "] - " + error.message);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure about the Parse REST api. Honestly, I'm thinking about trying another alternative. Any ideas out there? tks

**UPDATE:** I tried the *Jake T.* suggestion also without success. I've got the user correctly one time, and suddenly couldn't anymore. With 141 errors. I could access the user email, but couldn't fetch the hole user with it.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkUser3", function(request, response) {
  var user = request.user;
  user.fetch().then(
    function(user)
    {
        //Do stuff with the user now
        console.log("----checkUser3 - _User: " + user.get("email"));
        response.success( user );
    },
    function(error)
    {
        response.error("There was an error fetching your user: " + error.message);
    }
  );
});
```

Log:

- v157 Ran cloud function checkUser3 for user ASDASDASD with:
  Result: {"__type":"Object","account_type ... **SUCCESS**
- Ran cloud function checkUser3 for user ASDASDASD with:
  Input: {}
  Result: undefined **ERROR?**
- v157 Ran cloud function checkUser3 for user DFDFGDFG with:
  Input: {}
  Result: undefined **ERROR?**

Answer (score 0):

That's client code. For cloud code, use `var user = request.user;`

request.user is set to the user who made the cloud code request.  However, the object that returns from request.user is just the "shell" of the user, with an object id and created at date.  If you want the full user object, you'll have to then fetch this user. Using promises:

```
var user = request.user;
user.fetch().then(
    function(user)
    {
        //Do stuff with the user now
        response.success();
    },
    function(error)
    {
        response.error("There was an error fetching your user: " + error.message);
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried your code and I'm still getting 141 errors most of the time. In 5 tries that I made, I've got the user just in one, the other 4 throw a 141. I'm updating my answer with the log and code.

Comment: Can you call console.log(request); at the beginning of your cloud function and show us the code you're using to call this function? Also, output the user id of the current user from the client side just before calling the function.

I've never seen request.user not return a value, though I've only ever called cloud functions from a point I was logged in to a user saved to the server. Maybe you're creating a new user on the client side and trying to call a function before that user is actually saved to the server or something?

Comment: I'm making the request using the REST api via the Parse Console and also via Curl. I only have two users, both can upload, update and delete objs. All user objects are also protected with ACL. I confess that I'm dying with the REST Api of Parse. This is only one of the many issues that I came across. It's driving me crazy =/

Comment: In the REST Api (by my understanding) the _User is authenticated via sessionToken sent in the Header. Just so you know.

Comment: I've only used Parse cloud code and iOS SDK, so I guess I won't be able to be much more help :\ sorry.

Your logs say calling function xxxxx for user yyyyy, so I'd expect that they are properly made. However, all of my users have really random object Ids, so I'm not sure how you made yours ASDASD and what not. How did you get those objectIds?

Comment: Ah, that. lol. I put it there when I was editing to log to post it here. The real objId is pure gibberish. Lol. Thanks anyway. =)